# Datediff (minutes) excluding weekends counting the specified time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to add to the following script to additionally count the time only in the hours 10:00 <> 18:00. If the time `@StartDate` is 09:00 then we treat it as 10:00

Example:

```
SET @StartDate = '2021/12/10 09:00:00'

SET @EndDate = '2021/12/11 18:30:00'
```

The expected minutes result is the sum of minutes from 10:00 to 18:00 so 8*60 = 480 minutes.

Thanks for the tips

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2013/03/15 23:30:00'
SET @EndDate = '2013/03/17 00:30:00'


SELECT
(   DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate)
    - ( DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate,@EndDate)*(2*24*60)
        -- End on Sunday
        -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @EndDate)  = 1 THEN 24.0*60-DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,@EndDate),@EndDate) ELSE 0 END)
        -- Start on Saturday
        -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @StartDate) = 7 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,@StartDate),@StartDate) ELSE 0 END)
        -- End on Saturday
        +(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @EndDate)  = 7 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,@EndDate),@EndDate) ELSE 0 END)
        -- Start on Saturday
        +(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @StartDate) = 1 THEN 24.0*60-DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,@StartDate),@StartDate) ELSE 0 END)
    )
)
```

Comment: This is when a Calendar table or Tally would be most useful.

Comment: Any solution? The above works fine but the enumeration in the context of the time interval is missing and I'm wondering how to bite it, because the query is almost ready :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
DECLARE @MinDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @MaxDateTime DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2021/12/10 09:00:00'
SET @EndDate = '2021/12/10 18:30:00'
SET @MinDateTime = CONVERT(datetime, CONCAT(CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate), ' 10:00:00'))
SET @MaxDateTime = CONVERT(datetime, CONCAT(CONVERT(DATE, @EndDate), ' 18:00:00'))

 SELECT
(   DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate)
    - ( DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate,@EndDate)*(2*24*60)
        -- End on Sunday
        -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @EndDate)  = 1 THEN 24.0*60-DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,@EndDate),@EndDate) ELSE 0 END)
        -- Start on Saturday
        -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @StartDate) = 7 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,@StartDate),@StartDate) ELSE 0 END)
        -- End on Saturday
        +(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @EndDate)  = 7 THEN DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,@EndDate),@EndDate) ELSE 0 END)
        -- Start on Saturday
        +(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @StartDate) = 1 THEN 24.0*60-DATEDIFF(minute,CONVERT(date,@StartDate),@StartDate) ELSE 0 END)
    )
),
DATEDIFF(minute, CASE WHEN @StartDate < @MinDateTime 
                   THEN @MinDateTime
             ELSE @StartDate
        END,
        CASE WHEN @EndDate > @MaxDateTime 
                   THEN @MaxDateTime  
             ELSE @EndDate
        END) AS diff
```

Test it [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/146431)

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation, in addition to having working code, so that the OP learns from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just another Option (Brute Force).

Can span multiple days.  Can be expanded to include holidays.

```
Declare @Date1 datetime = '2021/12/10 10:00:00'
Declare @Date2 datetime = '2021/12/12 18:30:00'

Select Minutes = count(*)
 From  ( Select Top (DateDiff(Minute,@Date1,@Date2)+1) D=DateAdd(MINUTE,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
          From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
       ) A
 Where datepart(WEEKDAY,D) not in (1,7)
   and convert(time,D) >= '10:00' 
   and convert(time,D) <  '18:00'
   and convert(date,D) not in ('2021-12-25','2022-01-01')  -- Holidays: Should be a table
```

**Results**

```
Minutes
480
```

Comment: Aside: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Comment: @HABO Fair enough.  I actually prefer to use DATENAME(WEEKDAY, ... ), but I noticed OP used 1 & 7